# Can't figure out how to get result i want from query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to databases and mysql. I'm having a difficult time even deciding exactly what the problem I'm facing is and don't really know what the relevant google search would be. So forgive me if this is a mind-blowingly retarded question. I have two tables `tabs` and `cats`.

`tabs` is like this:

```
name | order
tab1 | 3
tab2 | 0
tab3 | 1
tab4 | 2
```

`cats` is like this:

```
name | tab_name
cat1 | tab3
cat2 | tab3
cat3 | tab1
cat4 | tab1
cat5 | tab1
```

I guess it's a one-to-many relationship tabs-to-cats. My question is how can I structure a query that will return only distinct tab names, each with all of its associated cats? I can get a result with all the cats and many duplicate tabs. Or I can get only distinct tabs but only one cat per tab. Maybe I should just be testing for duplicate tabs with my php code? Or querying tabs then querying all the cats for each tab? It just seems like there has got to be a more direct way. I'm currently using this query:

```
SELECT t.name AS tab, c.name AS cat FROM tabs t
LEFT JOIN categories c
ON t.name=c.tab_name
ORDER BY t.order;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to produce a comma-separated list of `cat`, if that is what you want:

```
SELECT
  t.name AS tab,
  GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) AS cats
FROM 
  tabs t 
  LEFT JOIN categories c ON t.name = c.tab_name
GROUP BY tab
ORDER BY t.`order`   /* ORDER is a reserved keyword and has to be quoted as `order` */
```

This would produce output like:

```
tab      cats
------------------------------
Tab1     Cat1,Cat2,Cat3,Cat4
Tab2     Cat4,Cat3,Cat6,Cat7
```

#### However,

the query you have which produces multiple rows per `tab` is a more conventional way to handle this. In your application code, you would loop over the `tab cat` pairs and test for a change of the `tab`.  If you use the `GROUP_CONCAT()` above, you would also need to split it on the `,` in your application code.

Either way, you cannot get a hierarchical result row-wise in the SQL - you have to repeat `tab` for each row. That's just the nature of the 2-dimensional structure of a result set. So it will require some application-side processing.

Comment: Beat me to it, that's what I was going to suggest.  Great answer.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much! I'll have to pay more attention to mysql functions. I knew I couldn't get varying rows but I thought maybe I could get null values for repeats, that way they simply wouldn't print. It seems much easier to process if I just use explode() and another loop for each tab.

Answer (score 2):

SQL ain't the best fit for hierarchical queries; however, your query output lends itself well for processing inside the application:

```
$tabs = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $tabs[$row['tab']][] = $row['cat'];
}
```

If you also need distinct categories:

```
    $tabs[$row['tab']][$row['cat']] = $row['cat'];
```

It generates a two-dimensional array with tabs as the first dimension and categories as the second.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's essentially what I was doing except I'm using pdo so my query already comes in an array...I probably should've mentioned that. Anyway, if I can loop over csv within the initial loop it seems to muck up my code less than looping over the whole result twice before the values are printed.

Comment: My answer is also based on PDO actually :) if your names will never have commas and you don't need to fetch any auxiliary data then that's fine too I guess :)